How to add outline as a navigation index in quarto
I want to add the ouline as part of the HTML render from my quarto document. One can see it at the top right when executing the code, but how can I add this outline as a navigation index at the start of the document?

Below, the code that produces the outline:
---
title: "my example"
format: html
editor: visual
---

## Introduction

### First paragraph

### Second paragraph

## EDA

### Third paragraph

### Fourth paragraph

## Methodology

### Big long paragraph

## Results


Do you mean https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-basics.html#table-of-contents?
